# Is is possible to use federated identities in AWS Cognito for my web/mobile apps?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I know that user pools allow to authenticate users to my apps, but what about federated identities? As far as I understand, they allow only to grant access to the AWS resources, not to the app. Or am I not right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Federated Identities only provide you short term AWS Credentials to access AWS resources. If access to your app is based on AWS resources then you can use Federated Identities otherwise User Pools is a better fit.